# Change the language of ““YourApp” Would Like to Use Your Current Location”

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

When using location services, I get this message: ““YourApp” Would Like to Use Your Current Location”

Is there any way to change this to another language, even if the iOS language is set to English? (My app comes in one non-English language only, so it’s weird to have that English dialog pop up in my non-English app.)

Comment: I can't confirm this, but I think that this is handled by the OS, and no app could change this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `CLLocationManager`, you can set its [`purpose`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW30) property to any text you like.

This text will be displayed in addition to and under the standard "AppName Would Like To Use Your Current Location" text.

Comment: As of iOS 6, `purpose` is deprecated.  Use new Info.plist key NSLocationUsageDescription instead.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562152/replacement-for-purpose-property-of-cllocationmanager.

Answer (score 2):

I would be very surprised if you can do that!
This is a matter of user privacy and it should be stated in the language selected by the user not you (developer).

Answer (score 1):

On stock OS iOS devices, the language of OS privacy warnings is under user control, not an app's control via any public API.