# Permission to access contacts not asked after deleting and reinstalling app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

With iOS 6, as per user's contact privacy, an app has to request permission to access Contacts. I referred to this answer provided here: [**How to localize iOS 6 new Info.plist Privacy purpose strings?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12564347/how-to-localize-ios-6-new-info-plist-privacy-purpose-strings/14144989#14144989) to localise `infoPlist.strings` file and I did like this which asks for Contact access permission for the first time:

```
 "NSContactsUsageDescription" = "App would like to access your Contacts? Allow?";
```

But during the testing I found that if I delete the app and run/install again it does not ask for permission to access contacts again. I even rebooted device after deleting app and ran again but same reason. Am I missing something here in setting Contacts permission?