# MKMapView alert customization

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, ios5, uialertview

When you first time launching app with MKMapView, application shows alert with message " would like to use your current location" with options "Don't Allow" and "OK".

I need to **customize this message**. Also I need to know **which option user selected**. How can I achieve this?

UPDATED:
I need to implement this on iOS 5+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### for custom message

for the message you can use the purpose property as Alex Terente said, but it has been deprecated in iOS 6

#### to get the option

for knowing if the user denied the permission the location Manager provides a failure delegate. the mapview uses its own location manager so: use the `MKMapView` function  `didFailToLocateUserWithError`

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didFailToLocateUserWithError:(NSError *)error {
switch([error code]) {
                case kCLErrorDenied:{
                    //user denied
                }
                break;
            }
}
```

note: if you are using a CLLocationManager directly it'd be `- (void)locationManager: (CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError: (NSError *)error;`

Comment: dont think this works!? Doesnt the map view have its own locationManager?

Comment: you were right, if he only uses the MKMapView but isn't using a CLLocation manager my answer isn't going to work, I've updated my answer, this should work.

Comment: yes, I have rewritten it show the mapview error first though because then the answer better matches the question

Answer (score 3):

On [CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) set purpose property

From this question: [Replacement for "purpose" property of CLLocationManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562152/replacement-for-purpose-property-of-cllocationmanager)

The Anna Karenina answer

> The replacement for the purpose property in iOS 6 is a new Info.plist
>   key named NSLocationUsageDescription (aka "Privacy - Location Usage
>   Description").
>
> The key is documented in the Information Property List Key Reference
>   but unfortunately it's not mentioned with the deprecation note of the
>   purpose property.
>
> However, the CLLocationManager.h does have this comment:
>
> - Deprecated. Set the purpose string in Info.plist using key NSLocationUsageDescription.
>
> In your code, you could set both the key and the purpose property (but
>   you may want to check if the location manager responds to that
>   selector first if/when that method is actually removed in the future).
>
> If running under iOS 6, the location manager will use the key. When
>   running under less than iOS 6, the key will be ignored and the purpose
>   property will be used.

Comment: purpose is deprecated in iOS 6

Comment: MKMapView does not have CLLocationManager, how I can set `purpose` property then? Also trick with NSLocationUsageDescription works, but it does not customizing message, it just add additional text below default alert message

Answer (score 0):

If you're building for iOS 6+, use the [`NSLocationUsageDescription`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW18) in your `Info.plist` file. Insert this key and set its value as the description of what you will do with location information.