# Change system pop-up in iPhone app for core-location permissions

Tags: ios, iphone, uialertview, core-location, cllocationmanager

Instead of system default below popup for core location permissions, how can I use my default pop up for my app?

[image]

And when does this popup come? Is it coming on particular delegate Method?

Is there any way to disable that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This popup comes when you access this `locationServicesEnabled` property of CLLocationManager.

```
[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled];
```

You `can` handle this in your app. But anyway, you `cann't` handle it **first time** according to [apple's doc(see locationServicesEnabled topic](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW31).

```
locationServicesEnabled
```

Returns a Boolean value indicating whether location services are enabled on the device.

```
+ (BOOL)locationServicesEnabled
```

**Return Value**
YES if location services are enabled; NO if they are not.

Discussion
The user can enable or disable location services from the Settings application by toggling the Location Services switch in General.

> You should check the return value of this method before starting
>   location updates to determine whether the user has location services
>   enabled for the current device. Location services prompts users the
>   first time they attempt to use location-related information in an app
>   but does not prompt for subsequent attempts. If the user denies the
>   use of location services and you attempt to start location updates
>   anyway, the location manager reports an error to its delegate.

After disallow, try to attempt,

```
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled)
{
    //Do your work
}
else
{
   if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
        {  //Show Alert view... }
}
```

Comment: @ios Give upvote if it's really useful to you which make more attention for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

You can not replace that UIAlertView but cutomize the text to hopefully explain better why your app needs access to the user's location.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562152/replacement-for-purpose-property-of-cllocationmanager